# Why does using a raw form tag rather than Using(Html.BeginForm) break client-side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I found out that after replacing @using (Html.BeginForm) with the regular `<form>` tags broke the client-side validation.
When I viewed the source, the html output is the same, except for the re-ordering of the tags.
Why would this prevent the client-side validation from working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you call `Html.BeginForm` it sets a form context variable which has the effect that helpers such as TextBoxFor, CheckBoxFor, ... emit HTML5 data-* attributes when generating their corresponding input fields. Try for example using one of those helpers without a form and you will see that the input doesn't have any HTML5 data-* attributes which are used by client side validation.

You could cheat by manually creating the form context:

```
@{ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();}
<form ....>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

But hey, why would you need to manually hardcode a form instead of using the corresponding helpers which will take care of properly generating urls, methods, encoding, ...?

Comment: Thanks, I was experimenting with T4Mvc, and then found out that I can still use the generated strings with the BeginForm helper.

Comment: @Darin: I'll give you a reason to manually hard code a form. `BeginForm()` doesn't support HTML attributes *and* keeping any query arguments in the URL when the form is submitted. Unfortunately, I see no great solution in this case.